# IONIC 5 ionic serve produces Error: NGCC failed

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

I created a new ionic 5 project by using

`ionic start myApp blank`

When I run the project in browser using `ionic serve` it has given the following error

**Error: NGCC failed**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out the problem my self

The problem was when I was installing the latest npm packages

it was installing the **typescript: 4.0.2** and thats why the **NGCC error**
occured

run the following command and it will work,

```
npm i typescript@">=3.9.2 <4.0.0”
```

Or in future some one faces this error this is about the typescript version so just install the valid typescript and you will fix the ngcc error